# Using mpdf with codeigniter generate blank output

Tags: codeigniter, pdf-generation, mpdf

I have been flowing this [post](http://www.badcaffeine.com/index.php/blog/comments/Using-mpdf-with-codeigniter-to-generate-pdfs-from-html-and-css/) to generate a pdf but the output is blank and there is no error displayed , i have put :

```
public function generate_pdf()
{
    $this->load->library('mpdf');
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>HTML content goes here...</p>');
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

When i put :

```
public function generate_pdf()
{
    $this->load->library('mpdf');
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4');
    $mpdf->debug = true;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>HTML content goes here...</p>');
    $mpdf->Output();
}
```

referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123433/874800) , i get this error :

```
Output has already been sent from the script - PDF file generation aborted.
```

Comment: Check your error logs - it could be that a PHP warning or error could be adding output before you get a chance to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is  working using  **ob_end_clean()** that erase the output buffer and turn off output buffering

```
public function generate_pdf()
{
   ob_end_clean();
   $this->load->library('mpdf');
   $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8','A4');
   $mpdf->debug = true;
   $mpdf->WriteHTML('<p>HTML content goes here...</p>');
   $mpdf->Output();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some output is already sent to the browser from your script. Please check your source code. You may want to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) as well.

Comment: i have wrap my code with ob_start(); annd  ob_end_clean(); but it still not working

Comment: Output buffering won't help if your code is generating errors as you'll be buffering the errors into your output as well.  Given you're setting debugging on, it's obviously going to be generating log messages.