# mPdf Creates a blank page

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have an html invoice that I want to convert to pdf. I used mpdf for this, but in the case of an additional page without data, how can I delete this extra page?
I used the following method but it did not work.

```
ob_start();  
echo $html;  
$html2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
```

This is the output : [img_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hzoN.png)

my code : [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb251ed6351b8597b4391c84d05b0966b4dd319c)

Comment: [You can find it here,This question is already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737042/mpdf-no-output-blank-page)

Comment: @SKASIFALI The answers to this question did not help me

Comment: There are a number of possible reasons -- (1) script error (it will cause such "blank page" behaviour in mPdf (2) possible overflow of data (even a single blank line) causing the pdf generation to add an extra page, etc. But without more information it is not possible to give further advice.

Comment: @KenLee I added my code to the question

Answer (score 1):

I changed 'margin-top' from 313px to 308px and it removed the additional page.

```
 @page :first {
 header: html_firstpageheader;
 margin-top: 308px;
 }
```

Additional page issue occurs generally due to margin and padding which creates invisible content (overflow of content).

Comment: @Dragon,  did this help?